# Login from PHTML template (1.9) [Resolved]

Tags: magento-1.9, login, registration, custom-template

The problem was that the following:

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
```

Had to be added to:

```
   template/customer/form/register.phtml
```

---

I am using the following inside a PTHML file:

```
if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
  echo "<h1>YOU ARE NOT LOGGED IN</h1>";
  echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/form_register')->setTemplate('customer/form/register.phtml')->toHtml();
  echo "<br><br>";
  echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/form_login')->setTemplate('customer/form/mini.login.phtml')->toHtml();
}
```

This creates the forms, as expected, however when I fill out the registration form and click the submit button I am directed to:

```
domain.com/customer/account/create/
```

When I fill out the login form I am redirected to:

```
domain.com/customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cDovL2Rldi53d3cucHJvdGVjdHlvdXJib3VuZGFyaWVzLmNhL2N1c3RvbWVyL2FjY291bnQvaW5kZXgv/
```

The user is not successfully logged in at this point.

I don't see any errors in the log files. Am I missing something? I wonder could it be related to the formkey stuff that was added?

My ultimate goal is:

1. User comes to Page X while not logged in.
2. User registers and/or logs in. (this is where I am stuck)
3. User is returned to the Page X. (I have an observer that should work once above is solved)

Comment: Just a minute to late ;) - if adding the form key fixed your problem please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the following:

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
```

Had to be added to:

```
   template/customer/form/register.phtml
```